# Higlight mouse position on click or click and drag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I need some sort of visual feedback of mouse position when it is clicked or clicked and dragged within a widget or a rectangular area. The visual feed back should stay where the mouse is released. I did something like the following, but it is not exactly what I'm tying to do:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class test(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(test, self).__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.handle = QPushButton()
        self.handle.setFixedSize(15, 15)
        self.handle.setParent(self)
        self.handle.setText("+")
        self.handle.setStyleSheet("background: none;"
                                  "border: 1px solid;"
                                  "border-radius: 7px;")

    def mousePressEvent(self, pos):
        if pos.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.handle.move(pos.x(), pos.y())
            print(str(pos.x()) + ", " + str(pos.y()))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, pos):
        if pos.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.handle.move(pos.x(), pos.y())
            print(str(pos.x()) + ", " + str(pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = test()
    t.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problems with the above code are:

The button's position is calculated from its top left corner, so I have to do something like

```
self.handle.move(pos.x() -7, pos.y() -7)
```

to make it appear in the center, which is very inconsistent.

The visual feedback should stay within the widget or area and not go out of bounds when the mouse does. Again, I could work around that with a few lines of inconsistent code (as I'm not an expert).

I was looking for something that can help me with achieving it and the best best thing I come across was to install pyqtgraph. But I doubt if it will take more resources and adding a new library is going to complicate things for me. Or is this my best bet?

The image below shows something similar.

[image: colorPicker]

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the post, it is enough to take into account the geometry of the dragged element and the window:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel


class TestLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestLabel, self).__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.handle = QLabel(self)
        self.handle.setFixedSize(15, 15)
        self.handle.setText("+")
        self.handle.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid;" "border-radius: 7px;")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.rect().contains(event.pos()):
            self.handle.move(event.pos() - self.handle.rect().center())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and self.rect().contains(event.pos()):
            self.handle.move(event.pos() - self.handle.rect().center())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = TestLabel()
    t.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is this the only way; updating widget position?  Something similar I found was how those color picker's let you move around  a handle inside an area to pick color. I couldn't find any sources to learn about that. Or it is something similar?

Comment: @x0_0x I do not understand you, explain yourself better

Comment: I've updated the question with what I was talking about.

Comment: @x0_0x mmm, nowhere in your post do you indicate that you want 2 crossed lines, or do you think we are fortune-tellers? You only pointed out that with your solution you had some drawbacks that my answer clearly solves them.

Comment: I'm not talking about the two lines, the intersection of the lines shows mouse coordinates. This method seems much more consistent than what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the name of the place where I drag the mouse in pyqt

## position where mouse is released

```
 def dropEvent(self, event):   # Drag and Drop in Camera View
        
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()

        format = 'application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'
       
        name_str = codecs.decode(data,'utf-8')

        if mimeData.hasText:
           
            destination = self.childAt(event.pos()) # position where mouse is released
            destination.objectName()                # object name where mouse is released
```